# PyQt5 unable to find Wayland plugin

Tags: python, pyqt5, wayland, qtwayland

I am currently trying to run a program written to use PyQt5 in a Wayland session on KDE Neon, but I am encountering this error when I attempt to launch it:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "wayland"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

It was suggested to me that I make sure that qtwayland5 is already installed on my system, and that is the case, so that doesn't appear to be the source of the issue.

Additionally, I have confirmed that this issue persists with using both the version of PyQt5 found in my distro's repos as well as with the latest version of PyQt5 installed within a virtualenv.

Comment: XCB is an X11 client-side protocol binding, which suggests you're actually using X11 (which is meant for backwards compatibility), either via an X11 back-end of Wayland, or just using an X11 session.

Comment: Which distro are you using? And specifically which package(s) are you using? How did you install Qt and PyQt5?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind running on xcb instead of Wayland, you could always unset `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland` (which is set on login with KDE wayland) and your app will run under XWayland.